# Отправить POST запрос

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

Нужно отправить `POST` запрос с параметрами и прочитать `html` в ответе. Вот мой метод :

```
public string HTMLContent(string uri, string postparametters = null)
{
    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;                
        using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (postparametters!= null)
                {
                    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                    byte[] postByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postparametters);
                    stream.Write(postByteArray,0, postByteArray.Length); //!!!Ошибка
                }
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(httpWebResponse.CharacterSet)))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот строка POST параметров `postparametters` :

```
"CountTypeId=1&InGameExchanges=313&InGameIssuerId=185 280&Opener=FORM&UnderlyingType=3&filterBlockClosed=false"
```

На `stream.Write` падает исключение - `NotSupportedException`. Поток не поддерживает запись. Как это исправить ?

Comment: Как насчёт [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015324/5752652)?

Comment: @AK `Параметры длины контента или поблочного шифрования не могут быть заданы для операции, не осуществляющей запись данных`

Comment: А зачем Вы пытаетесь писать в ResponseStream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется вы немного путаете `get` и `post` запросы.

В `GET` запросе идет отправка данных путем добавления необходимых параметров в саму адресную строку, что в итоге выглядит примерно так: `сайт/resource?param1=value1&param2=value2`

В `POST` запросах правильней отправлять данные в теле запроса. Обычно это идет путем создания на сайтах различных форм.

Давайте посмотрим на скажем вот такой код:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(CancellationToken ct)
{
    string data;
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http...");
    string url = "/data.php";

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", "..."),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2", "..."),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param3", "...")
    });

    using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content, ct);
        var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        data = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Данный код отправит на указанный адрес запрос с телом, которое будет содержать закодированные параметры (param1, param2 и др..).

Пройдемся по порядку:

- `string data` - нужна нам для дальнейшего возврата ответа от сервера (будь то HTML или API)
- `var baseAddress = new Uri("http...");` - это корневой сайт, то есть `http://сайт.ру`. Без дальнейших значений по типу `/data.php`.
- `string url = "/data.php";` - тут как раз указываем `/data.php`.
- `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent` - это именно тело запроса, которое хотим отправить. `FormUrlEncoderContent` отлично сконвертирует все данные в подходящий для `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` запроса формат.
- Ну дальше все довольно просто, отправляется `POST` запрос с нашим телом и получаем ответ в кодировке `utf-8`. По поводу кодировки кстати, можно использовать что то вроде `data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`, убрав `bytes` и `encoding`, у меня лично сайт отдавал данные в кодировке `utf-8`, а не зарегистрированной `utf8`, все падало, пока явно не указал...

В общем, ваш запрос должен грамотно создавать тело по стандартам и вам надо узнать что именно должен получить сервер от вас, может это `JSON` данные...

Удачи, пробуйте, надеюсь поможет!

Comment: Я в принципе уже разобрался, но спасибо за доп пояснение. +10 вам в карму!)