# Раскодировать ответ

Tags: c#, кодировка, httpclient

С помощью класса `HttpClient` конекчусь к некоему API.
Получаю такой ответ:

```
<h1>�������������� ��������</h1>
```

Понимаю, что в теге заголовка что-то в закодированном виде, но вот как его в читабельный вариант перевести не могу понять.

Comment: Тут нету нечего закодированного. Просто вы получаете данные в неверной кодировке. Попробуйте указать ее явно!

Comment: Можно вопрос не по теме? А зачем API отдаёт ответ в html? Xml видел, json видел, html - как-то.... так себе.

Comment: @A K - я не знаю, такой у них апи

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  `var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url,
                new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).ConfigureAwait(false);`  Перепробовал все encoding.

Comment: @РоманТимохов Попробуйте [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/772106/220553) способом. Суть в том, что вы получаете байты и уж затем их переводите в нужную кодировку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, помогло.