# Отправка Json из c# на PHP-сайт методом POST

Tags: c#, post, xamarin, httpclient, json.net

Помогите пожалуйста со следующим вопросом:

Есть приложение Xamarin которое отправляет данные на сайт методом POST, 
На сайте проверяю, если ли такой параметр POST но вот проверка не проходит, как будто и нет параметра, проверял отправку данных через метод GET все работает отлично.

В текущем примере на сериализацию пускаю отдельный класс, в котором есть сериализуемый мне класс `KVMglob.korzinaModel`

Реализация класса `korzinaModel` ниже

Код отправки данных на сервер

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(KVMglob.korzinaModel);

HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

HttpContent responseContent;


if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    responseContent = response.Content;
    var json_new = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

Код класса, который сериализуется в JSON:

```
public class KorzinaModel 
{
    //...
    public int TotalSum { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Обработчик на сайте PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['TotalSum']))
{
    echo "true post";
}
```

**UPD**

при конвертировании моего объекта в JSON `StringContent(json)`, он имеет тип `text/plain` и в коде PHP метод `$_POST['TotalSum']` не сработает, подскажите, каким образом тогда можно отправить данные, чтобы его можно было прочитать в PHP через переменную `$_POST['TotalSum']`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправить POST запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772034/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: Сейчас попробую спасибо, если заработает отпишусь

Comment: если не заработает - тоже пишите, что попробовали и что не завелось - пишите это только в вопросе, а не в комментах

Comment: @tym32167 Ну вообще оно заработает, куда ж оно денется... но только если идти черезз FormUrlEncodedContent то тогда json не нужен, избыточен. Альтернатива - швырять прямо json, а на той стороне читать [при помощи FromBody](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/2.6.php) Так что топикстартеру нужно сначала определиться какой дорогой идти, а потом уже делать. И если объект "плоский", то можно и через FormUrlEncodedContent , а вот если объект сложный, с вложениями разных уровней - лучше FromBody.

Comment: @tym32167 Коллеги, пример который был приложен в 1 комментарии мне не подходит, у меня сложный объект, класс, в котором пару переменных и один список, соответственно мне необходимо передать все данные класса на сервер, как мне это можно сделать? пример который я пытался реализовать, находится по ссылке:https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/10.3.php
Но вот при отправке данных через POST условие существования переменной не срабатывает в PHP коде...

Comment: @Денис Вся ваша проблема в том, что вы не понимаете какой тип отправляете и пытаетесь принять. `$_POST['TotalSum']` принимает данные [application/x-www-form-urlencoded или multipart/form-data](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php). `StringContent(json)` отправляет данные в `text/plain`. Так что тут вы должны выбрать то, что все же хотите отправить! Если `text/plain` - переписывайте PHP (я с ним не знаком, но вот [как пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628491/6808809)). Если же хотите принимать `$_POST['TotalSum']` - переписывайте отправку данных.

Comment: Уважаемый, я же вам документацию скинул. `$_POST` принимает только `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` или `multipart/form-data`. Как их отправить из C# вам в первом же комментарии ответили. Не устраивает этот вид данных, тогда отказывайтесь от `$_POST`, ибо он не предназначен для этого! Попробуйте использовать `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Нет, в этом случае надо из php://input (это предпочтительнее, чем HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)  - где-то у меня был ответ, когда я больше на php писал, чем на c#... Добавил в ответ ссылку.

Comment: @AK Ну или так, я в PHP особо не разбираюсь. Просто странно видеть что после моего комментария с ссылкой на документацию, где явно написано о принимаемых типах появляется обновление в вопросе с текстом `отправить данные, чтобы его можно было прочитать в PHP через переменную $_POST['TotalSum']`. Тогда чем не устраивает первая ссылка, не пойму...

Comment: Товарищи, связываться с JSON скорее всего не буду, т.к. небольшой парсинг на javascript придется писать в PHP


@EvgeniyZ первый способ чем мне не нравился, что мне придется свой парс писать на вставку значений из массива, но видимо по всему придется его написать, в процессе реализации, как задачку решу, обязательно отмечу задачку решенной и приложу решение. Спасибо за вашу активную помощь

Comment: @Денис JSON это очень хороший вариант для передачи данных, но опять же, `$_POST` не принимает обычный текст, он создан для форм. Я бы на вашем место попросту переписал бы метод  в PHP для приема текста. Можете пойти костыльным способом, отправляйте `FormUrlEncodedContent` с одним значением (скажем `string Data`) и в него  засовывайте JSON. Тогда да, на PHP вы сможете сделать `$_POST['Data']`. Так что решайте, все необходимое мы вас вроде как разъяснили и показали...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ опыта в отправке данных на сервер ранее не было, распарсить в C# и отправить данные так, чтобы читалось в PHP через $_POST получилось, но мне этот вариант не очень нравится, прислушаюсь к вашему совету, и "научу" PHP работать с JSON , ВСЕМ спасибо за помощь! =)

Comment: PHP не надо учить json, он уже давно умеет: см. json_decode

Comment: @AK Благодарю, в теле вопроса внес информацию о том, как решил задачку, огромное спасибо))

Comment: Не надо вносить в тело _вопроса_ ваш _ответ_: вам нужно создать ещё один ответ и на нем уже поставить галку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD что в итоге получилось)**
Код в C# не менял, так же сериализую свой класс в JSON

На стороне PHP обрабатываю данные следующим образом:

```
// получение данных в POST 
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
// преобразование в JSON , параметр true означает, что преобразовать в ассоциативный массив
$data = json_decode($postData, true);


// пример получения данных из ассоциативного массива
// в моев случае это был 1 массив типа объекта и 1 параметр, это общая сумма
$Name_item=$data['ItemsBuy'][0]['Name']; // 
$TotalSum=$data['TotalSum'];
```

ЗЫ Если возникло непонимание, почему мы не можете добраться до своих данных, то вот вам онлайн декодер JSON
http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode
Вставьте туда параметр `$postData` и он вам распарсит вашу строку
Надеюсь кто сюда наткнется, получит ответ на свой вопрос

Еще раз всем огромное спасибо за помощь! =)

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта отправки POST, вам нужно определиться какой вам больше подходит.

Первый вариант - это отправка данных через FormUrlEncodedContent, удобно для "плоских" данных вида ключ-значение.

Например, у вас есть плоский класс с десятками полей int или string:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Процедура отправки:

```
public async Task<string> Send(object request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    const string serverUrl = "https://localhost:44365/api/values";

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(request.AsDictionary().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.ToString()));

    var response = await client.PostAsync(serverUrl, content);
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

(Где extension `.AsDictionary()` - можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210428/5752652))

И, например, если у вас на той стороне asp.net то приёмник - примитивный экшн:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post(MyRequest request)
{
}
```

Второй вариант - когда у вас MyRequest - объект с многими уровнями вложенности и очень хочется отправить через Json.

Отправка (сериализуем при помощи Json.Net):

```
public async Task<string> Send(object request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    const string serverUrl = "https://localhost:44365/api/values";

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(serverUrl, content);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Приёмка:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody]MyRequest request)
{
}
```

Если же у вас на той стороне сайт на PHP - то [читайте php://input](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php) - у меня был [подобный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694108/213987), отправляю туда.