# Исключение во время сериализации HTTP

Tags: c#, httpclient, response

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Встречались ли вы с проблемой, что сайты указывают некорректное значение `charset` в `ContentType` заголовке ? Т.е. указывают `cp1251`, а не `windows-1251` и при сериализации содержимого `HTTP` выдаёт исключение `InvalidOperationException`.

Я вышел из ситуации и при таком исключении в `catch` проверяю наличие кривого значения, меняю на нормальное и ещё раз пытаюсь сериализовать.

Но может быть как то иначе это можно делать ?

А не тупо:

```
string contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet.ToString();
contentType = contentType.ToLower();

if (contentType.Contains("cp1251"))
{
   response.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "windows-1251";
}
```

UPD:
Вот хороший пример, [facebook.com](https://www.facebook.com/) тоже выдаёт исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем исправлять при исключении, фактически уже после обработки, если можно сразу проверять и не получать исключение?

Comment: Я сталкивался как то с подобным, работая с одним "буржуйским" сайтом, который неверно писал кодировку, пришел к банальному - конвертировал прямиком полученные байты в нужную мне кодировку. Если что, подобная реализация есть [в этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772034/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81/772106#772106) ответе.

Comment: @ГеннадийП т.е. каждый проверять и те 99% нормальные, теряя процессорное время ? Или дурной тон в catch проверять ? Я падаван в этом деле, а вы мои магистры xD Было бы здорово, если бы разъяснили.

Comment: @Vipz Проверка и замена по маленькому словарю занимает крайне мизерное время по сравнению с повторной задачей (в данном случае сериализация плюс другие задачи)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял вас, спасибо! Вот мне много таких попалось, даже вообще не дописанные значения. А такой вопрос на перёд, если я буду все извлекать в `utf-8` - не будут ли на каких то иероглифы вылезать ? Допустим если `windows-1251`, а я его как `utf-8` получу по вашему методу.

Comment: @ГеннадийП круто, понял что пытались мне донести, спасибо!

Comment: `если я буду все извлекать в utf-8 - не будут ли на каких то иероглифы вылезать?` - конечно будут. Вообще я бы на вашем месте нашел бы способ автоматически "детектить" кодировку полученных байтов, ну или делайте словарь, как вам уже дали ответ. Вот например нашел на [EnSO ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853721/6808809), который автоматически обнаруживает кодировку байтов и выдает преобразованный текст, вам достаточно заменить `byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);` на параметр и заменить из моего ответа строки преобразования на это: `_ = detectTextEncoding(bytes, out data);`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `конечно будут` - исчерпывающий ответ. Спасибо! Буду теперь разбираться и думать. Всё же словарь в моём случае будет проще, чем детект xD Наверно даже просто двумя `if` 1251 и 8 буду вылавливать. Потому что другие я пока кодировки из 200к ссылок не встречал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы не плодить кучу `if` при проверке можете использовать словарь и поиск по словарю:

```cs
        Dictionary<string, string> charsetDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "cp1251", "windows-1251" },
            { "win1251", "windows-1251" },
            { "utf-8", "UTF-8" },
            { "utf8", "UTF-8" },
        };

        string charsetTest = "cp1251";
        Console.WriteLine(charsetDict.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == charsetTest).Value ?? charsetTest);
```